Understanding Order Book Imbalance When a New Queue is Established on Liquid Stocks
I’m currently studying order book dynamics on liquid stocks and I have a question regarding the order book imbalance when a new queue is established.
In a liquid stock when a new queue is established, the volume imbalance is very low when a new bid queue is appeared and very high when a new ask queue is appeared.
When a new bid/ask queue appears in the order book and the order book imbalance is very low/high, how does a trader decide whether to enter this new queue?
In that case how can order book imbalance be used to predict the next tick price movement?
Edit:
It looks like this paper Lehalle, Charles-Albert & Neuman, Eyal. (2019). Incorporating Signals into Optimal Trading. Finance and Stochastics. 23. 10.1007/s00780-019-00382-7. https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00847 has some information about this case.

For my question, the stocks always have 1 tick between best bid and best ask. When the best ask is consumed, the second best ask become the best ask queue and a small new bid queue is starting to form. In that initial phases, best ask (previously 2nd best ask) is very huge compared to the new bid queue. However, by the time the newly created best bid queue is growing. Then, it's going to be a tick up or tick down, depending on how fast that bid can grow but in my case usually it is tick down after a tick up (but not always)

I'd like to learn about if we believe the predictive power of the order book volume imbalance to predict the next tick move, how to handle a new queue establishment because it's always too skewed. However, there are orders joining to these very small new queues.

Hi: If you don't get a response, it's probably because you're treading in the deep waters where things get very propietary. I don't know the HFT field but, like everything else, it's competitive because everyone is going after the same TON of pennies.

I wonder the impact of the order book imbalance on these cases but you might be right.

I know charles cao ( penn state at the time ) had a paper on the order book imbalance but it was like 15-20 years ago so of course a lot has gone on since.  Maybe you want to check that out just for the heck of it. I have no idea if it could help you ?

Here it is but as I said, it's been too long so I don't know if it would be helpful to you. https://www.academia.edu/106919703/The_information_content_of_an_open_limit_order_book
